# Teamviewer for Mac VPN?

Tags: mac, vpn, teamviewer

I wonder if there is any VPN Option in Teamviewer for Mac.
There is no option to install it on Setup and there is no guide in the manual howto install the VPN.

I wonder if there is any Teamviewer VPN Adapter for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a VPN option for mac. But you can use the built-in VPN which you can configure in the `System Preferences-->Network Preferences`
[image]

Then you can add a new vpn-connection
[image]

So, you can easily configure a VPN by yourself. But Teamviewer for mac doesn't bring it with it.

Comment: The bad thing is, that it does not work with Teamviewer IDs, anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: What do you mean with teamviewer Ids?
The connection will go through the vpn. Or did i understand something wrong?

Comment: The thing is that you need a VPN server. Teamviewer for Windows allows you to establish a VPN between the 2 parties that are connected via teamviewer. What @c0dev suggested requires a VPN server on one of the two hosts, along with all the involved setup.
I havent found a usable replacement. The closest that you will get is with Hamachi, however, the free version limits you to 5 computers and is not "peer2peer" style.

Comment: Seems like there's still no solution here.  Current working solution is Teamviewer to local PC -> VPN Teamviewer to remote.

Comment: @pfrank can you please explain it a little better ? I'm trying to find a solution for that ...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question